# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first 2

Tags: java, android, data-binding

I am getting this error when adding cardview to recyclerview items. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and where to remove the parent view? And also can someone explain why am I getting this error? Thanks.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View"/>

        <variable
            name="chatsViewModel"
            type="com.sukshi.sukshichat.viewmodel.ChatsViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln_item_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:onClick="@{chatsViewModel::onItemClick}"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:visibility="@{chatsViewModel.sender ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_user_photo"
            style="@style/AppTheme.CircleImgList"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/circle_iv_border"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp"
            app:photoUrl="@{chatsViewModel.photoUrl}"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_person"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

`

And this is how i am inflating my layout

```
 mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ChatsItemHolder>(User.class, R.layout.adapter_item_chats,
            ChatsItemHolder.class, refUsers) {
        @Override
        public ChatsItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            AdapterItemChatsBinding adapterItemChatsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater
                    .from(parent.getContext()), viewType, parent, false);
            return new ChatsItemHolder(adapterItemChatsBinding);
        }
```

Here is my ChatItemHolder

```
public static class ChatsItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            private AdapterItemChatsBinding mAdapterItemChatsBinding;

            public ChatsItemHolder(AdapterItemChatsBinding adapterItemChatsBinding) {
                super(adapterItemChatsBinding.lnItemRow);
                this.mAdapterItemChatsBinding = adapterItemChatsBinding;
            }

            public void bindUser(User user, ChatsViewModelContract contract) {
                if (mAdapterItemChatsBinding.getChatsViewModel() == null) {
                    mAdapterItemChatsBinding.setChatsViewModel(new ChatsViewModel(user, mEncodedMail,
                            contract));
                } else {
                    mAdapterItemChatsBinding.getChatsViewModel().setUser(user);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: add one parent-layout to CardView

Comment: same issue again

Comment: try change the last param to true.

Comment: didn't works.thanks

Comment: @stackover65 can u post ChatsItemHolder?

Comment: Done...please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

Change the ChatsItemHolder constructor to

```
public ChatsItemHolder(AdapterItemChatsBinding adapterItemChatsBinding) {
    super(adapterItemChatsBinding);
    this.mAdapterItemChatsBinding = adapterItemChatsBinding;
}
```